# draw a chart with pointer in android

Tags: android, pointers, graph, charts

how I can draw a chart with a pointer that specify a point of chart and return information of that point. pointer is movable.
I want to show the information of Specified point below the chart.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Check the following libraries:

https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart

https://github.com/diogobernardino/WilliamChart

https://github.com/lecho/hellocharts-android

They are beautiful and maybe they have what you need.